# How do I pick the order in which windows are stacked or shown side by side?

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

For example I want Notepad, Word and Excel to stack side by side in that order, but when I right-click taskbar and click "Show windows side by side" it's in some random order every time.

I tried clicking the windows in the order I want them to be stacked or shown side by side, and that doesn't work. I tried clicking them backwards, arranging on the screen so that they are somewhat in the placement I want them, but they get rearranged according to some secret rules I don't understand.

How do I choose the ordering for stacking/side-by-siding windows?

Comment: They’re *either* stacked *or* side by side though. Which is it that you want?

Comment: it's actually both, I don't get how either of them chooses the order.